# any function to get top max 3 array elements in php

Tags: php

I have array in this form:

```
Array([a]=> 45 [b] => 86 [c]=>675 [d]=>2 [e]=>41 [f]=>87)
```

I want to print elements with top 5 value only.

Comment: I don't mean to be rude, but I'd expect a user of your reputation to have done at least a little amount of research before asking a question. You could've found out a solution with very little efforts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will preserve your index:

```
asort($arr);
$arr = array_reverse($arr);
$result = array_slice($arr, 0, 3);
```

Output

```
array (size=5)
  'c' => int 675
  'f' => int 87
  'b' => int 86
```

[asort()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php) sorts your array in ascending order and preserves the keys. [array_reverse()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php) reverses the values to get the numbers in descending order, and finally [array_slice()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) will extract only the first 3 elements.

**[DEMO](https://eval.in/146988)**

Comment: thanks, only `array_slice` is enough tooo i think

Comment: Or you could leave out `array_reverse()` bit by reverse sorting the array: `arsort($arr); $result = array_slice($arr, 0, 5);`.

Comment: @user123 That will return only the first three elements from the initial array. You need to get it sorted first, I just noticed the first answer using `arsort()` and `array_splice` is a faster approach.

Comment: @AmalMurali Yea, I realized it late, well there are too many array functions enough to make me forget.

Comment: why down vote rather up vote?

Comment: @user123 Though I can guess the reason (no effort from your part), that's not me.

Comment: I recommend use in function asort next flag - `SORT_NUMERIC` compare items numerically.

Answer (score 4):

```
arsort($array)
array_splice($array, 0, 3);
```

Comment: +1 this is the most efficient answer.

Comment: Except it wouldn't work. See [demo](https://eval.in/146995).

Comment: @AmalMurali ah sry, fixed it now

Comment: @TomášTomííkBlatný: It wouldn't still be correct. The output is incorrect. See [demo](https://eval.in/147502)

Comment: @AmalMurali now ur demo is incorrect, you must print_r(array_slice(...)), because the result is returned, the original array is not changed. https://eval.in/147544

Answer (score 1):

```
$your_array = array('a'=> 45, 'b' => 86, 'c'=>675 ,'d'=>2, 'e'=>41, 'f'=>87);

arsort($your_array);
$result = array_slice($your_array, 0, 3);
```

Comment: This wouldn't preserve the keys.

Comment: [You're welcome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23489263/any-function-to-get-top-max-3-array-elements-in-php/23489384?noredirect=1#comment36018919_23489452) ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use array_slice and rsort

```
$array = array('a'=> 45, 'b' => 86 ,'c'=>675, 'd'=>2, 'e'=>41, 'f'=>87);
rsort ($array);

var_dump(array_slice($array, 0, 5, true));
```

Result:

```
array(5) { [0]=> int(675) [1]=> int(87) [2]=> int(86) [3]=> int(45) [4]=> int(41) }
```